# BaseActivity repeating the child's action in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

I was trying to create a base activity and setup some things that would be applicable for all activities. However, when I was trying to test it, I see that what I was String "Example" that I was displaying is showing twice instead of once. If I remove the oncreate method from the base activity, it works as expected(shows up once). Any suggestion?

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
public class LauncherActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        Log.d("Test", "example");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See official doc about [setRequestedOrientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)), which will trigger the activity restart, then call `OnCreate()` method again.